# Tiny swarms and weapons with multiple damage types

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, swarm

I've just run an encounter for my players with several [Carrionstorms](https://aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Carrionstorm). While doing so, one of my players with a weapon that did both Bludgeoning and Piercing damage (Akashic Mysteries' Hand Cannons veil, but a claw natural attack should have the same issue). Since a Carrionstorm is a Tiny Swarm, it takes 1/2 damage from piercing and slashing weapons, but full damage from bludgeoning. Does this attack deal full damage since it's bludgeoning, 1/2 damage because it's piercing, 3/4 from it being both bludgeoning and piercing, or something else?

I know that if this was just DR/Bludgeoning then the attack would overcome it fine and if the attack had wording like [Flame Strike](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Flame%20Strike) to split the damage between the two (or more) types, then it would do 3/4 (or whatever fraction) damage - assuming one type was bludgeoning and the other piercing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### They deal full damage

The rules on weapon properties clears this up when explaining [Types](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Weapon%20Qualities&Category=Weapons)

> Some weapons deal damage of multiple types. If a weapon causes two types of damage, the type it deals is not half one type and half another; **all damage caused is of both types. Therefore, a creature would have to be immune to both types of damage to ignore any of the damage caused by such a weapon.**

We can extrapolate a little to see that this should apply to types of reductions that aren't 100% as well.